# How to use a C function in a NASM program?

Tags: c, nasm

I have a blackbox-26.obj file with a `function int purposelike(int a, int b)` written in **C**. It is necessary to write a program in assembler (NASM), where I would add two arguments via push and call this very function, then I would work with eax (where the response from the function was transferred). But how can I do it?

I tried to write like this:

```
...
extern purposelike
...
section .text
global start
start:

push dword 456
push dword 123
call purposelike
...
```

then `nasm -f win32 l6.asm` in cmd. But when `golink /console /entry:start l6.obj msvcrt.dll` an error occurs

> error!
> The following symbol was not defined in the object file or files:-
> purposelike
> output file not made

Answer (score 0):

Since we are compiling with the "purposelike" function, it must also be included in the line with golink...

```
golink /console /entry:start l6.obj blackbox-26.obj msvcrt.dll
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).